# What was the point of the bridge scene?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In [X-Men Origins: Wolverine (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/?ref_=nv_sr_1) there is a scene with Kayla and Logan driving in the car when they approach a bridge with two trucks going opposite directions stopped, blocking the way.

Logan gets upset and goes to nicely ask the guys to move. They give him grief, but before he rocks their world, Kayla intervenes, calming the truck driver. The driver then turns around and leaves; there is no incident.

What is the purpose of this scene? Is it to show that Kayla has some kind of power? From what I've read, she doesn't have any powers that allow her to manipulate other people. When Logan and Kayla get back into the car, they have an exchange about it where Kayla denies having power because Logan still got out of the car.

So what was the point of this scene?

Comment: She has the power to manipulate people's thoughts & actions by touching them. Havn't you seen the full movie, especially the ending scene where Kayla touches Strikers feet & he points his gun on his chin. But Kayla lets him go & makes him walk far away

Comment: @KharoBangdo ... Yes, she tells Striker something like, "*Walk 'till your feet bleed, then keep walking.*"

Comment: She didn't deny having powers, she told him straight out when he asked that she did have the power of persuasion. So he went on to ask if it worked on him too, she then said, "well you didn't stay in the car, did you?" Watch the movie again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the scene was to show that she has the power to command others when she makes physical contact and that Wolverine doesn't know she has powers.  She denies having power because she doesn't want him to know.  She's trying to manipulate him for Stryker and Sabretooth so if Wolverine found out it would ruin the plan.

EDIT:  modified answer to remove mention of Wolverine being immune to Kayla's powers since it's unclear whether he is immune or not.

Comment: My confusion is why she has the power to persuade others since reading through several Wiki's that don't list this as one of her powers. However, I found that they gave her this power for the film as stated here: http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Kayla_Silverfox

Comment: That link also states that she CAN persuade Logan.

Comment: @DustinDavis Her movie power is different from her power in the comics.  I found another [wiki](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Kayla_Silverfox) for the movie Marvel universe which says "...it appears that Logan and Victor Creed are immune to her ability due to their healing factors".  We know it doesn't work on Sabertooth because she can't stop him but maybe it does work on Logan at least to some degree.  I'll edit my answer since it's unclear.

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot of ambiguity between the movie version and comic version.

Answer (score 0):

She had the power to persuade others by touching. Not only in this scene, she uses her power on Stryker and forces him to walk. She could have killed him by making him commit suicide but didn't due to her nature.

Victor seems to be immune to her power due to his own healing power or some other mutant power which is not clear in movie. The same applies for Logan as he also posseses similar powers.

Her powers are mentioned in the [Wikipedia acticle on Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine):

> Wolverine's native-American (Blackfoot/Niitsítapi) mutant love interest and pawn of Stryker. She has the powers of tactile telepathy and hypnosis which allows her to control or convince others to do the things she wants them to by physical touch.